# Tensor product of irreducible finite dimensional representations of algebras A and B

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ are algebras over an algebraically closed field.
Then I want to prove that if $V$ is an irreducible finite representation of $A$ and $W$ is an irreducible finite representation of $B$ then the tensor product $V \otimes W$ is an irreducible representation of $A \otimes B$.

The proof I am reading is as follows. ([Book](http://math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf) by Etingof etc)

> By the density theorem, the maps $A \to \mathrm{End} V$ and $B\to
> \mathrm{End}W$ are surjective. Therefore the map $A \otimes B \to
> \mathrm{End} V \otimes \mathrm{End}W=\mathrm{End}(V\otimes W)$ is
>   surjective. **Thus,** $V\otimes W$ is irreducible.

The part I didn't understand is "thus" part.
Why the surjectivity $A \otimes B \to \mathrm{End}(V\otimes W)$ implies that $V \otimes W$ is irreducible?

Comment: There are no proper subspaces of $V\otimes W$ invariant under $\operatorname{End}(V\otimes W)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $V\otimes W$ is not irreducible it contains an invariant subspace $U\leq V\otimes W$. Now, choose a basis for $U$ and extend to a basis for $V\otimes W$. Using this basis, the image of elements of $A\otimes B$ in $\mathrm{End}(V\otimes W)$ are all block upper triangular. In particular, the map
$$A\otimes B\to\mathrm{End}(V\otimes W)$$
is not surjective.